# How to access search box of any website using python?

Tags: python

I know many questions were asked in this same context but i am not able to find a generic solution(that works on most of the websites)

I want to search in a website through search box provided in them and store those links generated as a result of my search query.But all the solutions i found are for only a particular website and they even didn't store the result of search query. Any idea how can i achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every website is different.
for example website No.1 might have called their search parameter 'q' while website No.2 might have named their search parameter 'search'
Examples :

http://example.com/search.php?search=

http://example.com/search.php?q=

A good approach would be to store every parameter name in a dictionary  and iterate over it while getting the resulting links for every page .
To exemplify , you could do

```
pages = {'http://example.com/search.php?':'q','http://example23.com/php_search?','search',and so on}
```

Comment: yes correct but see some website are developed using html and some using asp. in that case even search.php will be different. so the dictionary is going to be big

Comment: No, it wouldn't. You just have to adjust the examples to your preferred webpages :
pages = {'http://example.com/search.asp?':'q','http://example23.com/search_php?','search',and so on}

Comment: i am not getting. See what i want that user should input 2 elements 1 is website home url and other is the search query. Now if a website is developed in html so its search url will be like http://www.example.com/search.htm? and if it is in asp then http://www.example.com/search.aspx? . so how can i make a single dictionary key for both?

Comment: You can't . What I mean is that you can't cover that many webpages,
Make a dictionary like :
`{'http://example.com':'/search.php?q=','http://example23.com','/search.html?search=',and so on}`
This script is just impractical you cannot store every website's search parameter name but onlt a few

Comment: I didn't actually help btw, so my answer did not deserve to be accepted. :)

Comment: all i need is a way to go on. that's what your answer give. thats why i accept it